# Why does SonarQube claim the `return` line is not covered by a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube

Here's my API endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public int Post(SearchHistory searchHistory)
{
    IDashboardRepository dashboardrepos = new DashboardRepository();
    int historyId = dashboardrepos.SaveSearchHistoryByUser(searchHistory);
    return historyId;
}
```

And here is the SonarQube report:

[image]

The two green bars on lines 37 & 38 indicate that they are covered by the unit test. But for some reason like 39 isn't?

Here's the test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GlobalSeach_PutTest()
{
    SearchHistory history = new SearchHistory {
        // redacted for ease of reading on SO
    }
    var controller = new GlobalSearchController(_config);
    int? response = controller.Post(history);
    Assert.IsTrue(response != null);
}
```

Comment: Speculation: it's being misled by (lack of) debugging symbols; the declaration and the return statement are actually end up compiled together as one (`return dashboardrepos...`) as the local isn't used for anything else.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your test? Chances are `SaveSearchHistoryByUser()` throws an exception... This gets turned into a non-null 500 response, but doesn't hit the `return`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, well, I wouldn't be much of a developer if I didn't bebug my own test! Yes. I did. And no, it does not throw an exception.

Comment: We make no assumptions and have to go by what you post in your question, and that information is not in your question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that's what I thought too. But other endpoints follow the same format and SonarQube doesn't flag those return lines as not-covered.

Comment: You could add some code that does something with `historyId` before you return it just to see if @JeroenMostert is right.

Comment: @juharr, I'm going to combine them into a single line and see if SonarQube likes that: `return dashboardrepos.SaveSearchHistoryByUser(searchHistory);`. I have my doubts. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: As an aside I would expect your test's assertion to always be true, since the controller's Post method return an `int` and not and `int?`. Either you will get some non-null value, or the test will have failed due to an exception.

Comment: @JonathonChase, yes, good catch. I have changed that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Post`method returns an `int`. On your test you are expecting to receive a nullable int (`int?`).

My gues is the problem is that your are not really testing the result of your method when you use this assert: `Assert.IsTrue(response != null);`. The first problem is that kind of test will never fail.

I imagine that your `dashboardrepos.SaveSearchHistoryByUser` method should return the primary key of the entity you just persist on your db. Based on that assumption I suggest you to refactoring your test as I describe below, to improve and solve the problem with coverage.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GlobalSeach_PutTest()
{
    SearchHistory history = new SearchHistory {
        // redacted for ease of reading on SO
    }

    // _dashboardreposMock is an example of Mock<IDashboardRepository>
    _dashboardreposMock.Setup(_ => _.SaveSearchHistoryByUser(It.IsAny<SearchHistory>)).Returns(1);

    var controller = new GlobalSearchController(_config);
    int response = controller.Post(history);
    Assert.IsTrue(response == 1);
}
```

Comment: Giving this a try. Will return and report.